# Why does Google Public DNS make you set up a proxy server for DNS-over-TLS to work on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, networking, dns, tls1.2

They require you to run a proxy server or something?

https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using#mac_os

Comment: If you scroll just above in your link you would see the same warning for Windows. DoT is not mainstream in Operating Systems right now, besides Android. Also your question is offtopic here as not related to programming.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek thank you. I should have done more research

Answer (score 4):

Google isn't making you do it. The reason you need the proxy is that macOS doesn't support DNS-over-TLS natively, so you need something to translate DNS-over-TLS into insecure DNS, the only thing macOS understands. If anyone is making you run the proxy, it's Apple.

Comment: Yeah, you're correct. I need to work on my English and lazy communication. Knowing what you just told me, would it be a better way to phrase it like this: `Why does Apple not support DNS-over-TLS by default on macOS Catalina?`

Comment: @timxor As far as grammar/phrasing, yes, but that type of question would not be well-received here. ("Why doesn't X support Y"? questions rarely are.)

Comment: Google Public DNS is available through standard DNS, DoT is not mandatory at all. Also there is currently not a lot of support for DoT, Android does it but it is probably the only mainstream case as people seem to prefer DoH.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek My reading of the question is that the asker wants to use DoT, so saying that you don't have to use DoT isn't helpful.

Comment: I'm not reading the question as you, and if the problem was "how to have DoT on MacOS" then it is completely irrelevant if it is to ask Google Public DNS or any other nameserver. Yet the question emphasizes this,

Comment: Thanks everyone, trying to get better at asking questions :D